# How can I know the distance between two coordinates?

Tags: java, coordinates

Maybe this is not the website I'm looking for to find answers but here's my issue.

I'm working on a Java program and I need to know the distance in meters between two locations given it's coordinates in format EPSG: 4326.

For example,

coordinate 1:

```
42.34839, 2.484839
```

coordinate 2:

```
42.27345, 2.23453
```

What is the system, mathematically, to know the distance difference between two coordinates?

Comment: Off topic for SO... "*Distance between two points P(x1,y1) and Q(x2,y2) is given by: d(P, Q) = √ (x2 − x1)^2 + (y2 − y1)^2*"

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_on_an_ellipsoid) helps.... @sleepToken but not for coordinates on a sphere (or almost)

Comment: maybe the [Great-circle distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) would suffice in your case

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of different algorithms for determining the distance between two points. Manhattan distance for example is quite simple IIRC, it's just abs(x1 - x2) + abs(y1 - y2).

```java
class Coordinate {

    private final float x;

    private final float y;

    Coordinate(float x, float y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public float manhattanDistance(Coordinate other) {
        return Math.abs(x - other.x) + Math.abs(y - other.y);
    }

    public float getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public float getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

```java
Coordinate first = new Coordinate(42.34839f, 2.484839f);

Coordinate second = new Coordinate(42.27345f, 2.23453f);

float manhattanDistance = first.manhattanDistance(second);

System.out.println("distance: " + manhattanDistance);
```

## Output

```
distance: 0.32524872
```

Comment: Manhattan distance does not work for coordinates on a sphere (ellipsoid). Units in X must have the same length as in Y, which is not true for longitude and latitude ((at least if you want an usable result)) But true, there are a lot of distances